# Display child element along with Parent in Rabl

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl, rails-api

I created rails-api application with rabl as json builder template. My models are below

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
end
```

I am return courses as json. My Course has Title and Credits and DepartmentId. My existing rabl is

```
collection @courses => :courses
attributes :id, :Title, :Credits
```

But i need to include department name which is in the Department table. So my json is

```
{
courses: 
  {
    course: {
      id: 1045
      Title: "Calculus"
      Credits: 4
    }-
  }-
  {
    course: {
        id: 1050
        Title: "Chemistry"
        Credits: 3
   }-
  }
}
}
```

I need as add department as next object after Credits. Is normal rails app, i can put **course.department.Name** in the html. but how in rabl? Please guidee me

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to add delegate in Course model

```
delegate :name, to: :department
```

then add

```
collection @courses => :courses
attributes :id, :Title, :Credits , :department_name
```